# Not able to restrict the number of arguments for an option with GetOptions in Getopt::Long

Tags: perl, arguments

My program is as follows:

```
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use Getopt::Long;

   my @letters;
   my @words;

   GetOptions(
      "letters=s{2}" => \@letters,
      "words=s{,}" => \@words
   );

   print "Letters: " . join(", ", @letters) . "\n";
   print "Words: " . join(", ", @words) . "\n";
```

When I run this program I get the output as follows:

```
   perl getopts.pl --letters a --words he she it
   Letters: a, --words
   Words:
```

`--words` is read as part of `--letters` arguments itself. I expect `GetOptions` to throw error message in this scenario. How to get this done.

Answer (score 6):

Change:

```
"letters=s{2}" => \@letters,
```

to:

```
"letters=s{1,2}" => \@letters,
```

...which allows 1-to-2 letters as the argument.

Comment: "1-to-2 letters" should be "1-to-2 words"?  Uhm, I guess you mean 1-2 "--letters" arguments.  Confusing having words and letters be the name of the arguments as well.

Comment: What I want is exactly two arguments, otherwise error out. Even I tried with "letters=s{2,2}" => \@letters           No help

Comment: If you want exactly two arguments, I'd change to "letters=s{,}" => \@letters, and outside GetOptions die or warn unless @letters==2

Answer (score 2):

A quantifier of `'{2}'` means "exactly two". So, it's even ignoring the second argument afterwards is a switch.

The GetOpt::Long text that you probably took this from:

```
GetOptions( 'coordinates=f{2}' => \@coor, 'rgbcolor=i{3}' => \@color );
```

Are specific conditions for which pairs and triads make sense. You want an *x* and a *y* coordinate, or you want a value for each part of an RGB specification. Just the way that you would expect `'cmykcolor={4}'`.

If you want at least one, up to the next switch, you can specify `'{1,}'` as your quantifier, and if you want "at most two", then `'{1,2}'` makes sense. Interestingly enough, the behavior of `'{,2}'` is exactly the same as `'{1,2}'`. It seems that as long as you specify a quantifier, it will suck up one more argument, *regardless* of whether or not the next argument is a switch.

So the quantifiers in [`Getopt::Long`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aLong) may look the same as regex, but they mean different things.